# HTTP request efficiency Angular 4+

Tags: angular, typescript, http, ionic-framework

I have a very broad, but simple question regarding http requests via Angular. I have an Ionic app using Angular http requests, but I'm not sure if I'm making the most out of what Angular has to offer for speed and efficiency. My current code for my POST request:

page sending data .ts:

```js
//calls provider function  
this.stemAPI.submitBOLData(this.submitAllData,this.reap.token).then((result) =>{
   //API response handled here               
      }, (err) => {
          //Error handled here 
        });
```

provider .ts

```js
import { HttpClient,HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
// import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
// import { interval } from 'rxjs/observable/interval';
// import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
// import { _throw } from 'rxjs/observable/throw';
// import { mergeMap, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}
  export class StemApiProvider {
  //POST form submitBOL
    submitBOLData(data,authToken){
      //console.log(data);
      const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
              'Content-Type':  'application/json',
              'Authorization': authToken
            })
  };
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     this.http.post(this.apisubmitbolUrl, JSON.stringify(data), httpOptions)
     .subscribe(res=>  {
       resolve(res);
     }, (err) => {
       reject(err);
     });
   });
  }
 }
```

The call works fine, but I know there is more efficiency that can be added. Also, I know the rxjs package offers functionality like "retry" if the call fails, but I'm not sure how exactly that can be implemented.

The biggest reason for this question is because my clients will potentially be using the app in areas where there isn't the best cellular connection so the API calls will potentially take longer and I if the connection happens to break I want to know what tools I can utilize to give user other options.

Edit: package.json

```html
{
  "name": "Test Project",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.10",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/ionic-webview": "^5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^4.15.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "^2.0.3",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "angular2-signaturepad": "^2.8.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.1",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic": "5.2.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-webview": "0.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "2.4.0",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.10.0",
    "ionic-selectable": "^3.0.3",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "ws": "^3.3.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "To locate you"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic": {
        "APP_ID": "",
        "CHANNEL_NAME": "Master",
        "UPDATE_METHOD": "background",
        "UPDATE_API": "https://api.ionicjs.com",
        "MAX_STORE": "2",
        "MIN_BACKGROUND_DURATION": "30"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You can try `Observable` instead of `Promise`. That is the recommended approach for `Angular2+` http requests.

Comment: What is the best way I can implement this in my current code? Should I handle everything in my provider? Or can I return the observable back to my pages and handle it there?

Comment: Your design looks fine. Handle everything back in your component returning observable from the provider. This facilitates manipulating your view directly. Return the same observable using rxjs `map` operator instead of returning Promise and then subscribe to it from your comp.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Thankyou for your feedback, will look into and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd urge you to use `HttpClient` if you're using `Http`. It was introduced in Angular 4.3 and if you use that, you aren't required to do `.map(res => res.json())`

You will first have to add it `HttpClientModule` to the `imports` array of your `@NgModule`.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
...
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [..., HttpClientModule, ...],
  ...
})
```

Angular `HttpClient` returns `Observable`s and not `Promise`s. That gives you an edge as you can use operators like `retry` *n times* in case there's a network error before showing the user an error message.

Your code can be significantly refactored for the same.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retry';
...
submitBOLData(data, authToken) {
  const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': authToken
    })
  };

  return this.http.post(this.apisubmitbolUrl, data, httpOptions)
    .retry(3); // This will retry 3 times in case there's an error
}
```

Where you're using this function:

```
this.stemAPI.submitBOLData(this.submitAllData, this.reap.token)
  .subscribe(
    res => { /* Do what you want with this error */ }, 
    err => { /* Error handled here */ }
   );
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-http-client-eg-with-rxjs?file=app%2Fstem-api.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, `HttpClient` is available in Angular 4 and 5 as well.

Comment: Yes, my bad!! I just verified that. Its available from 4.3. https://fullstack-developer.academy/angular-http-vs-httpclient/

Comment: Now, that is worth mentioning as the OP might be using a version previous to 4.3 Thanks a lot for your inputs :)

Comment: Thank You gentlemen for the feedback, I will try and make sure everything works before I mark as answer. Also, I am updating question with my dependencies.

Comment: So I had HttpClientModule imported in my 'app.module.ts' and I believe I am using it, I updated my provider for you to see. Although I think my imports for retry are incorrect

Comment: Error on retry:"Property 'retry' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>". Also the function is not returning anything.

Comment: @StephenRomero, my bad, it's not `operators`. It's `operator` in `import "rxjs/add/operator/retry";`

I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Okay awesome It's working perfectly! For some reason atom was giving me errors, but the process worked with no issues! Thank you for your help! By chance are there any other rxjs operators I can utilize to handle http requests more effectively?