# angular - subscribing to a service that uses http

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, single-page-application

Its my first time ever using angular and typescript.

I have this function in my service:

```
login(email: String, password: String) {
  let formData = {
    usuario    : email,
    senha      : password,
    retsession : true
  }

  console.log('go');
  return from(this.nativeHttp.post<any>(this.env.API_URL+'/login', formData, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})).pipe(
    finalize(() => console.log('ok'))
  ).subscribe(data => {
    console.log('back');
    console.log(data);
    this.token = "123";
  }, err => {
    console.log('Native Call error: ', err);
  });
}
```

Then I'm trying to call it from my `auth-login.page.ts` this way:

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
  this.authService.login(f.value.usuario, f.value.senha).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('login ok');
    },
    error => {
      console.log('eeeerrroowwww');
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
    }
  );
}
```

So I'm getting this error:

```
auth-login.page.ts(24,60): error TS2551: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Subscription'.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Exactly what the error message says: you can't subscribe to a subscription. Your service doesn't return an Observable. It subscribes to an observable and returns the subscription. You generally do not subscribe in a service. https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data

Comment: Also note that using from is useless, since .post already returns an observable. Setting the content type is useless too: HttpClient does it for you. And using `any` basically ruins the whole point of using TypeScript. Please, read the http guide.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52818321/6000966), this should help.

Comment: I tried with HttpClient before but got iOS issues... so now I'm trying with nativeHttp... sorry guys I'm too newbie in angular. Can someone write a practical example without `subscribe` or `from()` in this case?

Comment: What is nativeHttp? HttpClient works very weel and is one of the parts of Angular that is very well documented. Just use it.

Comment: what obj is this.nativeHttp?

Comment: @anderlaini any update ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the function "subscribe", you must make the observables and this.nativeHttp.post function is the "observable" function as default.

Please check this [link](https://angular.io/guide/observables).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your code to this

```
return this.nativeHttp.post<any>(this.env.API_URL+'/login', formData, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Then in your component just use the same code you have right now then you should be good

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
  this.authService.login(f.value.usuario, f.value.senha).subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('login ok');
    },
    error => {
      console.log('eeeerrroowwww');
      console.log(error);
    },
    () => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs');
    }
  );
}
```